# How do I filter out Unclassified points from a LAS file and generate contours and a .dem file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, laz

I downloaded lidar data from https://gis1.oit.ohio.gov/geodatadownload/ and imported a LAS file into QGIS.  I want to generate contours and a .dem file from the Ground data.

[image: Layers]

I have been able to generate contours using 'Export to Raster' and then 'Contour' but it contains data from the Unclassified points that I do not want.  I have tried filtering only the Ground points with 'Export to Raster' but I get an error when I use the filter.

[image: Export to Raster]

[image: Export to Raster Error]

I also want to be able to create a .dem file with only the Ground points.  I did this once before but cannot remember how I did it now.

Comment: Those LAS files are classified. Use Las2Las in the LasTools to "Keep_Classification_2" (Ground only).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this qgis plugin. It might be what you are looking for.

https://github.com/klakar/PcFilterSlider